# Is there a way to hide leading whitespace?

Tags: indentation

Some of the files I am editing have a huge amount of whitespace leading before each line, for example:

```
module Something
  module Inside
    class FinallyClass
      def each_method_adds_indentation_as_well
        # actual code
        # ..
        # ..
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And sometimes even more indentation happens before it actually gets into the code part which I work on.

Is there a way to condense one, or two levels of indentation somehow through a plugin or a setting? (while maintaining the file contents intact)

So that above would become

```
module Something
module Inside # (hidden indent level 1)
class FinallyClass # (hidden indent level 2)
  def each_method_adds_indentation_as_well
    # actual code
    # ..
    # ..
  end
end # (hidden indent level 2)
end # (hidden indent level 1)
end
```

Comment: `class Something::Inside::FinallyClass` also saves you two levels of indentation. I don't understand why so many Rubyists add so much unneeded indentation like that :-/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this with Vim's `conceal` feature:

```
" Hide one or two two-space indents
syntax match HideTwoIndents /\v^  (  )?/ conceal

" (Optional) Hide regardless of cursor position
set concealcursor=nvic

" Hide concealed matches without replacement chars completely
set conceallevel=2
```

This tells Vim to hide the first (and second, if that exists) level of indentation using a regular expression.

If this is something you want to use a lot (and not just a quick fix for a particular set of files) then you'll want to improve it to build the regular expression using your current `'shiftwidth'` value.

Because of [some odd behaviour with the way Vim displays concealed tabs](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14425/why-are-concealed-tabs-displayed-wider-than-a-single-tabstop), you'll need something slightly more complicated for tab indents:

```
syntax match HideOneIndent /\v^\t\ze[^\t]/ conceal
syntax match HideTwoIndents /\v^\t*\zs\t\t\ze[^\t]/ conceal
```

#### Further Reading

- `:help conceal`
- `:help 'conceallevel'`
- `:help 'concealcursor'`

Comment: Tried adding this to vimrc to test it out, but with no effect. I am using neovim, but I would hope that this would work as well?

Comment: @hakunin I haven't tried it in neovim, but it should work. Does it work if you enter the commands into an already running copy of neovim?

Comment: I think you may have to use autocmd or after directory to ensure it doesn't get overwritten by Ruby's syntax (didn't test).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker That was my thinking too: I was just trying to diagnose the issue first.

Answer (score 2):

I made a plugin that does this

https://github.com/fent/vim-relative-indent

It doesn't use the conceal feature. It instead scrolls the window to the right accordingly.