# Why are tabs adjacent to concealed tabs displayed wider than a single tabstop?

Tags: options, tab-characters, conceal

I just wrote the following code in [an answer to another question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/14422/343):

```
syntax match HideTwoIndents /\v^\t(\t)?/ conceal
set conceallevel=2
```

This works great if `'list'` is set *and* if `'listchars'` does not contain a value for `tab:`.

However, if `'list'` is unset *or* if `'listchars'` contains a value for `tab:` then if there are more than two tabs at the start of the line,  the first two will be concealed as expected, but the third will be displayed as though it has a width of 3×`'tabstop'`!

e.g. after running:

```
syntax match HideTwoIndents /\v^\t(\t)?/ conceal
set conceallevel=2
set tabstop=2
set list
set listchars+=tab:xy
```

Then the line:

```
<tab><tab><tab>Three tabs
```

will be displayed correctly when the cursor is not on the line:

```
xyxyxyThree tabs
```

but will be displayed incorrectly when the cursor is on the line:

```
xyyyyyThree tabs
```

I would expect it to displayed as below:

```
xyThree tabs
```

Is this documented behaviour, or should it be reported as a bug?

Comment: looks like a bug

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Okay thanks I'll report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got around to posting [this as a bug on Vim's issue tracker](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/5559) after stumbling across it in the [Unanswered Questions](https://vi.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes) section.

However, after a bit more investigation (which is included in the linked issue), I suspect that the problem is that the size/position of tabs is calculated *before* text is concealed, and that this issue will therefore be hard to address. I don't hold out too much hope that a fix is coming any time soon.